# Map draw show error - TypeError: k[bd].maps.Load is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I've a feature to draw polygon map in my website.

In console it through error 
*TypeError: k[bd].maps.Load is not a function*

my code

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=drawing" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/main.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/drawing.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var drawingManager;
      var selectedShape;
      var colors = ['#1E90FF', '#FF1493', '#32CD32', '#FF8C00', '#4B0082'];
      var selectedColor;
      var colorButtons = {};

      function clearSelection() {
        if (selectedShape) {
          selectedShape.setEditable(false);
          selectedShape = null;
        }
        document.getElementById('delete-button').disabled = true;
      }

      function setSelection(shape) {
        clearSelection();
        selectedShape = shape;
        shape.setEditable(true);
        selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
        document.getElementById('delete-button').disabled = false;
      }

      function deleteSelectedShape() {
        if (selectedShape) {
          selectedShape.setMap(null);
        }
        // To show:
         drawingManager.setOptions({
           drawingControl: true
         });
         document.getElementById('delete-button').disabled = true;
      }

      function selectColor(color) {
        selectedColor = color;
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
          var currColor = colors[i];
          colorButtons[currColor].style.border = currColor == color ? '2px solid #789' : '2px solid #fff';
        }

        // Retrieves the current options from the drawing manager and replaces the
        // stroke or fill color as appropriate.
        var polylineOptions = drawingManager.get('polylineOptions');
        polylineOptions.strokeColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('polylineOptions', polylineOptions);

        var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
        rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);

        var circleOptions = drawingManager.get('circleOptions');
        circleOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('circleOptions', circleOptions);

        var polygonOptions = drawingManager.get('polygonOptions');
        polygonOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('polygonOptions', polygonOptions);
      }

      function setSelectedShapeColor(color) {
        if (selectedShape) {
          if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
            selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
          } else {
            selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
          }
        }
      }

      function makeColorButton(color) {
        var button = document.createElement('span');
        button.className = 'color-button';
        button.style.backgroundColor = color;
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
          selectColor(color);
          setSelectedShapeColor(color);
        });

        return button;
      }

       function buildColorPalette() {
         var colorPalette = document.getElementById('color-palette');
         for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
           var currColor = colors[i];
           var colorButton = makeColorButton(currColor);
           colorPalette.appendChild(colorButton);
           colorButtons[currColor] = colorButton;
         }
         selectColor(colors[0]);
       }

      function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.886436490787712, 80.2685546875),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoomControl: true
        });

        var polyOptions = {
          strokeWeight: 0,
          fillOpacity: 0.45,
          editable: true
        };
        // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
        // markers, lines, and shapes.
        drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
          drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
          drawingControlOptions: {
            drawingModes: [
              google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
            ]
          },
          markerOptions: {
            draggable: true
          },
          polylineOptions: {
            editable: true
          },
          rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
          circleOptions: polyOptions,
          polygonOptions: polyOptions,
          map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
          if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE) {
            var radius = event.overlay.getRadius();
          }
          if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
            var coordinates=[];
            var polygonBounds=event.overlay.getPath();
            for(var i = 0 ; i < polygonBounds.length ; i++)
                coordinates.push([polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng()]);
            document.getElementById("paths").value = coordinates;
            //document.forms["frm_crds"].submit();
          }

        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
            if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
            // To hide:
            drawingManager.setOptions({
              drawingControl: false
            });

            // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
            // mouses down on it.
            var newShape = e.overlay;
            newShape.type = e.type;
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
               setSelection(newShape);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape.getPath(), 'set_at', function(event) { 
                var coordinates1=[];
                var polygonBounds1=newShape.getPath();
                for(var j = 0 ; j < polygonBounds1.length ; j++)
                    coordinates1.push([polygonBounds1.getAt(j).lat(), polygonBounds1.getAt(j).lng()]);
                document.getElementById("paths").value = coordinates1;
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(event) { 
                var coordinates1=[];
                var polygonBounds1=newShape.getPath();
                for(var j = 0 ; j < polygonBounds1.length ; j++)
                    coordinates1.push([polygonBounds1.getAt(j).lat(), polygonBounds1.getAt(j).lng()]);
                document.getElementById("paths").value = coordinates1;
            });
            setSelection(newShape);
          }
        });

        // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
        // map is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);

        buildColorPalette();
    var coords =<?php echo json_encode($coords);?>      
    var newCoords = [];
    var newPolys;
    for (var c = 0, cc = coords.length; c < cc; c++) {
        var point = coords[c];
        newCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng));
    }
    //console.log(newCoords);
    newPolys = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: newCoords,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    newPolys.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(newPolys , 'click', isWithinPoly);
    function isWithinPoly(event){
       var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, this);
        //console.log(isWithinPolygon);
    }
    addNewPolys(newPolys);
    function addNewPolys(newPoly) {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
        drawingManager.setOptions({
          drawingControl: false
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(newPoly, 'click', function(event) {
            var coordinates1=[];
            var polygonBounds1=this.getPath();
            for(var j = 0 ; j < polygonBounds1.length ; j++)
                coordinates1.push([polygonBounds1.getAt(j).lat(), polygonBounds1.getAt(j).lng()]);
            document.getElementById("paths").value = coordinates1;
            setSelection(newPoly);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(newPoly.getPath(), 'set_at', function(event) { 
            var coordinates1=[];
            var polygonBounds1=newPoly.getPath();
            for(var j = 0 ; j < polygonBounds1.length ; j++)
                coordinates1.push([polygonBounds1.getAt(j).lat(), polygonBounds1.getAt(j).lng()]);
            document.getElementById("paths").value = coordinates1;
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(newPoly.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(event) { 
            var coordinates1=[];
            var polygonBounds1=newPoly.getPath();
            for(var j = 0 ; j < polygonBounds1.length ; j++)
                coordinates1.push([polygonBounds1.getAt(j).lat(), polygonBounds1.getAt(j).lng()]);
            document.getElementById("paths").value = coordinates1;
        });
    }
    setMarkers(map, beaches);
          }
    var beaches = <?php echo json_encode($exst);?>;
    //console.log(beaches);
    function setMarkers(map, locations) {
       var image = {
        url: 'images/beachflag.png',
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
      };
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
      // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
      // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
      // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
      // coordinate.
      var shape = {
          coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
          type: 'poly'
      };
      var marker = null;
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var beach = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: beach[0],
            info: "<strong>"+beach[0]+"</strong><hr>"+beach[3],
            zIndex: beach[4]
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(this.info);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
      }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/common.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/util.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/controls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/drawing_impl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/onion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/stats.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/geometry.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/poly.js"></script>

  <form name="frm_crds" method="post">
    <input id="paths" type="hidden" name="coord[]">
    <div id="panel">
      <div>
      <div id="color-palette" style="display:none">

      </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button id="delete-button" type="button" disabled>Clear Map Draw</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>   
  <div id="map" style="position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

in post i find reason as *"duplication of js"*. I can't find which js file is duplicated in my script.

> note: if i remove main.js, it works in firefox. it doesn't work in chrome

Comment: Two things: 1. `var coords =<?php echo json_encode($coords);?>` does not look as valid javascript. 2. Remove **all** `<script>...</script>` lines but this one: `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=drawing" type="text/javascript"></script>` as it will load all required script files, including `main.js` - that is where the duplication is coming from.

Comment: @IvanJovovic Thanks. It worked after removing all external js except the one u mentioned.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I have added the solution in the answer section, please mark it as accepted one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **all** `<script>...</script>` lines but this one:

`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=drawing" type="text/javascript"></script>`

as it will load all required script files, including `main.js` - that is where the duplication is coming from.